# Azure Synapse Analytics Notebooks on local IDE

Tags: azure, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, azure-synapse

Is there a way to develop Synapse Notebooks using my local IDE? I would like to avoid using the Editor in the Synapse Portal.

I looked at the Synapse VS Code extension. However, this one only works for Fabric Synapse instances. We are not using those in my company.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no way to develop Synapse Notebooks using my local IDE.

You can raise the feature request for that [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c).

But as an alternative, if you want to use the Local IDE to develop Synapse notebook, you can first create the notebook in your local IDE and Save it in your local machine. Then you can import the required notebook in synapse.

[image]